# Append literal string (plain text) to XPath result

Tags: string, text, xpath, literals

Is there a way to append a literal string to whatever an XPath expression gets you?

e.g. from following XML:

```
<root>
    <select>I am</select>
</root>
```

I would like to produce:

> I am a literal

purely with XPath. What do I add to `/root/select` to get what I want? **Important: XPath 1.0 solution required!** I'm not using XSLT.

Comment: Do you mean append the literal string to the value of the node?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what situation you're talking about.  In XSLT terms, it would be `<xsl:value-of select="/root/select"> a literal`

Comment: @AsadAli yes, that's it.

Comment: @freefaller I'm not using XSLT, it's purely XPath. I'll see how it works internally tomorrow but I can tell now it's a C# implementation of something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any reason you can't simply concat() 'a literal' to the end?

Something like: `concat( string(/some/selector) , ' some literal' )`?

Comment: That will probably work, thanks! I'll test tomorrow and accept your answer if it does.